# How to hold specific package version?

Tags: ubuntu, apt, percona-xtradb-cluster

I have Percona XtraDB Cluster 5.6 installed on my Ubuntu server. Recently, when i tried to update my system using apt i see some new version of percona, but with an older version.

```
The following packages will be upgraded:
  percona-xtrabackup percona-xtradb-cluster-client-5.5 percona-xtradb-cluster-common-5.5 percona-xtradb-cluster-galera-2.x percona-xtradb-cluster-server-5.5
```

So i want to keep my 5.6 version and still update all the other packages. I try using some lines in the `/etc/apt/preferences.d`:

```
Package: *
Pin: release o=Percona Development Team
Pin-Priority: 1001

Package: percona-xtradb-cluster-*
Pin: version 5.6*
Pin-Priority: 550
```

But it doesn't work. I found many solution to not upgrade from 5.5 to 5.6 but nothing concerning my problem.

Comment: Which versions of the percona packages have you got installed? Do you have both the 5.5 and 5.6 versions? If so apt is doing the right thing and the fix would be to remove the 5.5 version leaving just 5.6.

Comment: I'm so stupid, you're totally right. I need to take some rest ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[turning my guess into an answer]

Sounds like you've got the 5.5 and 5.6 packages installed.

If so apt is doing the right thing. Fix is to remove the 5.5 version leaving just 5.6.